# Connecting MongoDB Atlas to Kubernetes EKS Cluster on AWS

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-vpc, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to setup an VPC Peering from my MongoDB Atlas Cluster to my Kubernetes EKS Cluster on AWS. The Peering is established successfully but i get no connection to the cluster on my pod's.

The peering is setup.
[image: Peering]

The default entry for the whitelist ist added as well. Once the connection works i will replace it with a security Group.
[image: IP Whitelist]

The peering on AWS is accepted and "DNS resolution from requester VPC to private IP" is enabled.
[image: Peering AWS]

The route as been added to the Public Route Table of the K8S Cluster.
[image: Route AWS]

When i connect to a pod and try to establish a connection with the following command:

```
# mongo "mongodb://x.mongodb.net:27017,y.mongodb.net:27017,z.mongodb.net:27017/test?replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0" --ssl --authenticationDatabase admin --username JackBauer
```

I get "CONNECT_ERROR" for every endpoint.

What am I missing?

NOTE:
I've just created a new paid cluster and the VPC is working perfectly. Might this feature be limited to paid clusters only?

Comment: Is your MongoDB in shard configuration?

Comment: Adding `--verbose` may give you some more info on what is the reason of the connection error

Comment: @FL3SH no its in replica set configuration

Comment: @esboych this is an output with --verbose: NETWORK  [thread1] creating new connection to:x.mongodb.net:27017
NETWORK  [thread1] connected to server x.mongodb.net:27017 (108.x.y.z)
NETWORK  [thread1] SocketException: remote: (NONE):0 error: 9001 socket exception [CONNECT_ERROR] 
[thread1] User Assertion: 6:network error while attempting to run command 'isMaster' on host 'x.mongodb.net:27017'

Comment: @thomas-spycher your case *might* look like an `ssl` issue. The `connected to server x.mongodb.net:27017 ` means you have connectivity on the network level.
To clarify further you may run `nc -v x.mongodb.net 27017` in advance. If you'll got something like `x.mongodb.net (108.x.y.z) 27017 (?) open` then you do have a connection at least on the network level.  So as a next step you may check `ssl`-related stuff like key/cert files or so.

Comment: upd: also if disabling `ssl` is viable option on Atlas you might temporarily disable it (or deploy test cluster with the same config and `ssl` disabled) and then just check on what's changed. In my own experience security options were always the most tricky to debug.

Comment: @esboych i think traffic is not routed via the peering. If i add 0.0.0.0 to the whitelist i can connect but looks like an external ip address.

Comment: would you pls expose the DNS tab content of your Peering Connections section from AWS console?

Answer (score 3):

Well... as the documentation states:

> You cannot configure Set up a Network Peering Connection on M0 Free
>   Tier or M2/M5 shared clusters.

Peering is not working on shared Cluster. Which makes, after i think about it, totally sense.

Comment: Ohh ok then it's about to be clear now. Btw you may consider DocumentDB of AWS which advertised as Mongo API-compatible and probably will have less trouble to connect from private IPs.